# Can SalesForce federated search be used in conjunction with content indexed in Elasticsearch?

Tags: api, global-search, federated-authentication

Disclaimer: I don't work within SalesForce at all, but I am being asked to research some capabilities. I apologize for the lack of SF knowledge; this is an exploratory question.

Need: We have a collection of HTML documents indexed in Elasticsearch, and we would like to be able to search that collection of documents from within a SalesForce Community site.

Is this possible or what are some alternative options? Any advice is helpful. Thanks.

Addition: Specifically, we have a static site with a search page that sends queries to an Elasticsearch index. We parse the results and print them as search results -- very basic. When reading the SalesForce Federated Search documentation, I see information about an OpenSearch Description, but I am unfamiliar with that and whether that needs to be set up (or can be set up) with our set up.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by alternatives? There are several search providers that integrate in salesforce. Some solutions are mote complex and expensive than others, what exactly are the functionalities you or your customer needs?

Comment: We have a separate static site for documentation, and users are able to browse and search that site independently of the community. Our need: give users the ability to see search results from this separate site within SalesForce. I was looking through the federated search documentation, but I am not sure about the OSD (OpenSearch Description) file -- what that's used for, how to create it, whether or not it's needed in our situation.

We don't require robust filtering or integration at this point. Our bare minimum goal is to surface an external site's search results within the community site

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: i work for a company that does that exactly (Coveo) . And yes, you are able to do so with elastic search as well, however, if you are going to integrate such functionality within a community in Salesforce, there’s quite a bit of coding involved, and considering how often the platform has releases, there’s quite a bit of maintenance to do as well.

Comment: Thanks for the disclaimer. We are looking at Coveo, and that provides what we need and much more. We're also evaluating other products and internally-created solutions to exhaust all options, price points, etc. Are there any resources available to help with this research? I added this to the main post: I've reviewed the SF federated search documentation, but I am unfamiliar with OpenSearch and how that works with a search front end that queries an ES index.